# What the settings for generating 15000 POST Requests per Second in JMeter for atleast an hour continuously?

Tags: python, post, jmeter, request, performance-testing

What the settings/approach for generating 15000 POST Requests per Second in JMeter for atleast an hour continuously?

As per project requirements: at-least 15K users will post messages per second and they will continue it for an hour or more.

What is the, Number of Threads, Ramp-up time, loop count ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Number of Threads: depending on your application response time, if your application responds fast - you will need less threads, if it responds slow - more, something like:

   - if your application response time is 500ms - you will need 7500 threads
   - if your application response time is 1s - you will need 15000 threads
   - if your application response time is 2s - you will need 30000 threads
   - etc.
2. Ramp-up - depending on the number of threads and your test scenario. A good option would be:

   - 10 minutes to ramp up
   - 60 minutes (or more) to hold the load
   - 10 minutes to ramp down
3. Loop Count: Forever. The duration of the test can be limited by "Scheduler" section of the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) or using [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) or you can manually stop the test when needed.

---

4. You can use i.e. [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) or [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) in order to set JMeter's throughput to 15k/second
5. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) as 15k requests per second is quite high load, it might be the case you will have to go for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) if you won't be able to conduct the required load from the single machine.
6. Make sure that JMeter machine(s) have enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, etc. as if JMeter will lack resources - it will not be able to send requests fast enough even if the application under test is capable of handling more load. You can monitor resources usage using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)